# Android Insert to sqlite database from .csv

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm in a bit of trouble with a sample program that I am writing.

Here is my code:

```
public void prePopulateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, Context helperContext){
    String fileIn = "";
    String[] file;
    ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
    AssetManager am;
    InputStream is = null;
    am = helperContext.getResources().getAssets();

    try {
        is = am.open("Matrix.csv");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while((fileIn = br.readLine()) != null){
            file = fileIn.split(",");
            row.put(KEYWORD, file[0]);
            row.put(DURATION, file[1]);
            row.put(AMOUNT, file[2]);
            row.put(DESCRIPTION, file[3]);
            row.put(LEVEL_NAME, file[4]);
            row.put(CHOICE_FOR_TWO_1, file[5]);
            row.put(CHOICE_FOR_TWO_2, file[6]);
            row.put(CHOICE_FOR_FIVE_1, file[7]);
            row.put(CHOICE_FOR_FIVE_2, file[8]);
            row.put(CHOICE_FOR_FIVE_3, file[9]);
            row.put(CHOICE_FOR_FIVE_4, file[10]);
            row.put(CHOICE_FOR_FIVE_5, file[11]);
            insertToDBViaContentValues(db, row);
        }//end while
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }//end try catch
}//end fxn

public void insertToDBViaContentValues(SQLiteDatabase db, ContentValues row){
    procedure("SiteMatrixMultiLevels: INSERT TO DB > "+row.toString());
        db.insert(TABLE_SITES, null, row);
}

public void validate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_SITES, null);
    if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            data("VALUE: " + c.getString(0) + "," + c.getString(1) + "," + c.getString(2) + "," + c.getString(3) + "," + c.getString(4) + "," + c.getString(5)
                    + "," + c.getString(6) + "," + c.getString(7) + "," + c.getString(8) + "," + c.getString(9) + "," + c.getString(10)
                     + "," + c.getString(11) + "," + c.getString(12));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

and I am getting an error of

```
02-03 20:24:04.537: W/System.err(16437): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7
```

at

```
row.put(CHOICE_FOR_FIVE_1, file[7]);
```

The csv file that I am fetching files from has multiple lines but only follows 2 formats.
The first 100 are of this format

```
pkey,keyword,duration,amount,description,A,B,,,,,
```

while another 100 follow this format

```
pkey,keyword,duration,amount,description,,,C,D,E,F,G
```

I am not sure if im getting the error because the first format type only stops at 7 (since no value for C,D,E,F,G is specified.)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: for no value add ""(blank)

Comment: hi Dhawal thanks for your response. Are you suggesting that if the length is 0, i manually add? I get all my data from the csv using row.put and as much as possible, I want to keep it that way. Without using if statements to determine if a column entry from the csv has no value.

Comment: @user1481694 a rule of thumb is to check if the index exist before indexing into it.

Comment: use CSV reader class like this question its easy for you http://stackoverflow.com/q/9663410/1168654

Comment: hi all. I'm a bit weirded out by this but, I went to the .csv file. replaced all ",,," with ", , ," (to add a blank space as a value) and it worked. funny thing, I removed all the spaces I added and now I am able to recreate it. (I deleted all my local data first before recompiling). I am going to leave this as open though, because in the future, when I might need to replace my csv, I wouldnt want to do this dumb quick fix again. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with you data. Here is what you need to for in your `split()` call...

```
file = fileIn.split(",", -1);
```

Thats all...

Actually you need to consult the documentation of [split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), as it says,

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Means you need to define second argument (limit) in it otherwise it will consider it as `zero '0'` and empty entries will be removed. So **pass -1 to get all the empty entries** as well.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Simple implementation. Try to use StringTokenizer.

```
private void readAndInsert() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {


ArrayList<SimpleQuestion> questions = new ArrayList<SimpleQuestion>();
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream is = null;

            try {
                is = assetManager.open("questions/question_bank.csv");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

            String line = "";
            StringTokenizer st = null;
            try {

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                    SimpleQuestion sQuestion= new SimpleQuestion ();
                                    //your attributes
                    sQuestion.setX(st.nextToken());
                    sQuestion.setY(st.nextToken());
                    sQuestion.setZ(st.nextToken());
                    sQuestion.setW(st.nextToken());
                    questions .add(sQuestion);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            yourDB.bulkInsert(questions );

}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for this answer as well. however, i feel that using split over st is the way to go, since i would not want to lengthen the code even more. :)

Comment: Thanks, too. Ok go on ;)