# How do I feed an InputStream into a CSVReader?

Tags: java, csv, inputstream

I want to convert `InputStream` into `CSVReader`. When I am using the code below

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(ADDRESS_FILE));
```

it is working fine, but, if I fetch the file from class path, then this code is not working.

How do I convert a `InputStream` to `CSVReader`?

This is not working cause `InputStream` is not a string type:

```
InputStream input = ImportCsv.class.getResourceAsStream("/dataUpload/staff.csv");
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(input));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSVReader and InputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663410/csvreader-and-inputstream)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
```

---

#### Edit to answer the comment

The problem is because you don't have any constructor for FileReader as you want. See the [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) API for details. But since you will have to convert the byte stream to character stream so you will have to use `InputStreamReader`. For better performance you can wrap it with a `BufferedReader` also

Comment: See my edited answer. Sometimes you may have problem with encoding, so if you have any mention the encoding format of your datasource like "UTF-8"

Answer (score 10):

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
```

The bridge between binary bytes / InputStream, and unicode text (Reader/String) is the InputStreamReader. Specify the encoding of the bytes / InputStream if the file is not local.